# A problem occurred while processing the request (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to migrate jenkins from old server to newer one. I have imported all the jobs and config from old server. But after making changes to job configuration in new jenkins, I am facing "A problem occurred while processing the request" error while applying and saving that job.

Old Jenkins Version: 2.289.1
New Jenkins Version: 2.289.1
openjdk version:11.0.11
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgLM6.png)
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5owB.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved.
It was happening because the permissions inside jenkins jobs directory were not set to jenkins:jenkins